# Using Application Context in a ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm new to android development, so this may be a silly question, but I can't seem to find the information I need...

I have an ImageLoader class that will download a picture from the internet and save it to the local cache folder, or simply retrieve it from that folder if this is the second time of asking...

```kotlin
class ImageLoader(private val url: URL?, private val context: Context) : ViewModel() {

    var image = MutableStateFlow<ImageBitmap?>(null)    
    var imageCacheFile: String

    init {
        imageCacheFile = context.cacheDir.path
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            loadImage()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun loadImage() {

        //...
        //load image from cache or url
        //...
        
    }
}
```

I access this in my `@Composable` function as follows:

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
val imageLoader = remember { ImageLoader(event.imageUrl, context) }
val image = imageLoader.image.collectAsState()
```

**The problem** is I'm getting a complier warning on the Context parameter:

```
This field leaks a context object More... (⌘F1) 
Inspection info:A static field will leak contexts.

Non-static inner classes have an implicit reference to their outer class. If that outer class is for example a Fragment or Activity, then this reference means that the long-running handler/loader/task will hold a reference to the activity which prevents it from getting garbage collected.

Similarly, direct field references to activities and fragments from these longer running instances can cause leaks.

ViewModel classes should never point to Views or non-application Contexts.
```

The summary of what I have read seems to conclude it's fine (and it works well), but I don't like warning and would like to resolve it rather than suppress it...

I'm also not really happy to be passing contexts around simply to know where my cache folder is - it feels like there must be a better way...

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you should be using the `viewModelScope` instead of creating your own CoroutineScope, which will leak the coroutine if the task is ongoing while the ViewModel is destroyed. Also, using `var` instead of `val` for a mutable flow is a code smell. Things will break if you actually use that property’s setter.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to use an [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel) which is an "application context aware viewModel".

It would look like this:

```
class ImageLoaderViewModel(private val url: URL?, application: Application) :
    AndroidViewModel(application) {
    val image = MutableStateFlow<ImageBitmap?>(null)


    init {
        val imageCacheFile = application.cacheDir.path
        viewModelScope.launch {
            loadImage()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestComposable(imageLoaderViewModel: ImageLoaderViewModel = viewModel()) {
    val image = imageLoaderViewModel.image.collectAsState()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that; however not clear how I should call it; what replaces the line `val context = LocalContext.current` to pass in?

Comment: That should work but if not, try ```context.applicationContext```, or just ```applicationContext```.

Comment: For my existing code, or with `applicationContext`; on the line `val imageLoader = remember { ImageLoader(event.imageUrl, context) }` - `context` is shown with the error `Type mismatch.  Required: Application Found: Context`

Comment: In the Composable, replace `context` with `context.application` and if that doesn’t work maybe you need to make it `context.application as Application`. Away from computer so can’t confirm. I think using the application in a Composable prevents it from being previewable, by the way.

Comment: `context` doesn't seem to have an `application` property (only applicationContext and applicationInfo)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope it works!